# Blender rendering plane screen

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I tried changing camera, removed environment still didn't render.

Changed view still the same, disabled bloom, AO still same

[image]

[image: the problem]

[image: reder settings]

[image: settings]

Comment: Can you share the file? https://blend-exchange.com/